# Java Publisher Sever chat program

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, publish-subscribe

I am trying to create a chat application which has one publisher, one server and multiple subscribers. The publisher(Sending to port 8000) sends a message to the server(listening on port 8000 and 5000) and which forwards it further to the subscriber(listening on port 5000).

Now so far I can create multiple publishers and the communication between server and publisher is working, however, I am not able to send it to the subscriber the message sent by the publisher

**Server Side Code**

```
package serverclient;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class Server extends Thread{
private Socket socket;
private int clientNumber;

public Server(Socket socket, int clientNumber){
    this.socket  = socket;
    this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
    if(socket.getLocalPort() == 5000)System.out.print("\nSubscriber "+ clientNumber +" is connected to the server");
    if(socket.getLocalPort() == 8000)System.out.print("\nPublisher "+ clientNumber +" is connected to the server");
} 

@Override
public void run(){
    try {
        BufferedReader dStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        while(true){
            synchronized(this){
                String clMessage = dStream.readLine();
                System.out.println("\n"+clMessage);
                // if(socket.getLocalPort() == 5000){
                    out.println("Hey the server is sending the message to subscriber");
                // }    
                //out.println("Hey the publisher has sent the message :  " + clMessage);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.print("\nError has been handled 1\n");
    }finally{
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.print("\nError has been handled 2\n");
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
    int subNumber = 0;
    int pubNumber = 0;
    ServerSocket servSockpub = new ServerSocket(8000);   
    ServerSocket servSocksub = new ServerSocket(5000);
    try {
        while (true) {
            Server servpub = new Server(servSockpub.accept(),++pubNumber);
            servpub.start();
            System.out.print("\nThe server is running on listen port "+ servSockpub.getLocalPort());
            Server servsub = new Server(servSocksub.accept(),++subNumber);
            servsub.start();
            System.out.print("\nThe server is running on listen port "+ servSocksub.getLocalPort());
        }
    } finally {
        servSockpub.close();
        servSocksub.close();
    }
}

 }
```

**publisher code**

```
 package serverclient;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;
```

public class Publisher {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{

```
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",8000);

    // reading from keyboard (keyRead object)
    BufferedReader keyRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    // sending to client (pwrite object)
    OutputStream ostream = sock.getOutputStream(); 
    PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);

    InputStream istream = sock.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader receiveRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));

    System.out.println("Start the chitchat, type and press Enter key");

    String receiveMessage,sendMessage;               
    while(true)
    {
        sendMessage = keyRead.readLine();  // keyboard reading
        pwrite.println(sendMessage);       // sending to server
        pwrite.flush();                    // flush the data  

        if((receiveMessage = receiveRead.readLine()) != null) //receive from server
        {
            System.out.println(receiveMessage); // displaying at DOS prompt
        }  
        else{
            System.out.print("Null");
        }
    }

}
   }
```

**subscriber**

```
    package serverclient;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.Socket;


   public class Subscriber {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{

    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",5000);

  // receiving from server ( receiveRead  object)
    InputStream istream = sock.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader receiveRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));

    System.out.println("Recive side");

    String receiveMessage, sendMessage;  
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.print("Hey man " + receiveRead.readLine() + "\n");
        if((receiveMessage = receiveRead.readLine()) != null) //receive from server
        {
            System.out.println(receiveMessage); // displaying at DOS prompt
        }  
        else{
            System.out.print("Null");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Any help is appreciated. I just want to figure out why subscriber is not reciveing message

Comment: You do not even attempt to send the message to the subscribers. In the `try` block of your `Server.run()` method you are just reading the incoming message from the input stream and answer the publisher who issued the messag and then wait for another message. You need to get the message to the server threads which handle the subscriber connection. I myself prefer custom EventListener for such tasks but there are many more possibilities.

Comment: Another flaw in your design is that you accept a publisher socket **then** a subscriber socket and then repeat. This does prevent that you can log on with two or more publisher at a time. In fact your server only accepts the pattern `publisher->subscriber->publisher->subscriber` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities to handle realm time communication issues. I myself prefer the use of Events / EventListeners.
Currently in your program there is no communication between the Server as such and the threads which handle the subscriber connection.

Also on a side node: even with a proper communication between publisher connection threads and subscriber connection threads it won't work now since you are using the same `Server` class. This does not only violate the [Single-Responsibility-Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html) but will also prevent the server from ever sending a message to the Subscriber.

Let's say you have establish a connection and your server class is now connected with the subscriber. What will happen?
The subscriber will loop until there is a message on the input stream of his socket. Good that is exactly what we want. But what does the server do? The truth is **exactly the same**. The first few statements in the `try` block of your Server's `run` method are to create a BufferedReader and read from it until a message receives. And now we have a socket on each site which will infinitly wait for some kind of message to arrive (which will obviously never happen since **both** are waiting for something).

To prevent this you should check if there is anything to read on the stream first:

```
while ( true )
{
    if ( socket.getInputStream().available() != 0 )
    {
      // reading logic goes here.... 
      synchronized ( this )
      {
            String clMessage = dStream.readLine();
            System.out.println( "\n" + clMessage );
            out.println( "Hey the server is sending the message to subscriber" );
       }
     }
     // what shall be done when not reading.
}
```

---

Now the second part. If you want to communicate between threads you need to implement some logic to do so. As stated above I love the concept of Listeners so i will show an **example** where I make use of them:

**MessageReceivedListener.java**

```
import java.util.EventListener;

public interface MessageReceivedListener
    extends EventListener
{

  public void onMessageReceived( String message );

}
```

Note: The interface does not have to extend `EventListener` since `EventListener`
is just a tagging interface. I myself still prefer to have this as a reminder for what purpose the interface is there.

**Server.java (excerpt)**

```
// New constructor since we will pass a Listener now. Also new local variable for it.
public Server( Socket socket, int clientNumber, MessageReceivedListener mrl )
  {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
    this.mrl = mrl;
    if ( socket.getLocalPort() == 5000 )
      System.out.print( "\nSubscriber " + clientNumber + " is connected to the server" );
    if ( socket.getLocalPort() == 8000 )
      System.out.print( "\nPublisher " + clientNumber + " is connected to the server" );
  }
```

The new constructor provides a way to pass the MessageReceivedListener to the Server object. Alternatively you can alsocreate a setter for it.

```
synchronized ( this )
      {
        String clMessage = dStream.readLine();
        System.out.println( "\n" + clMessage );
        out.println( "Hey the server is sending the message to subscriber" );
        mrl.onMessageReceived( clMessage );
      }
```

This is where the magic happens. After whe receive the message we just pass it to the `onMessageReceived(String message)` method of the listener. But what does it do exactly? This is what we define when creatinga Server object.
Here are two examples, one with anonymous classes (Java 7 and before) and on with lambdas (Java 8 and later).

**Example Java 7 and earlier**

```
Server servpub = new Server( servSockpub.accept(), ++pubNumber,
            new MessageReceivedListener()
            {

              @Override
              public void onMessageReceived( String message )
              {
                // call nother local method
                // this method would need to be a static method of Server
                // because it's in the scope of your server class
                sendMessageToSubscribers(message);
              }
            } );
```

Here we pass an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) as our MessageReceivedListener object and define it's behaviour (in this case just calling another method which will handle the rest.

---

Now since our *MessageReceivedListener* interface does only contain one method we can also see it as a functional interface and therefore use lambdas to shorten the code and improve readability.

**Example with Lambda (Java 8 and later)**

```
Server servpub = new Server( servSockpub.accept(), ++pubNumber, Server::sendMessageToSubscribers);
```

In this specific case we only have one argument which we want to pass to a method and therefore can use a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

How to actually implement the method `sendMessageToSubs(String message)` is up to you. But you need to keep track of how many Threads with subscriber connections have been created and how you want to reference them.

Comment: thanks very much I understand what I was doing wrong